# How to properly schedule script autorun as root in Debian

Tags: debian, cron

I need to schedule script (create_ap) autorun as root in Debian. I used cron for this (sudo crontab -e). It runs, but doesn't works. I think this is because its environment is different than one when I run script from regular user with sudo.
So, how to properly schedule autorun of this script?

Comment: What do you mean by `autorun`? My guess, based on you thinking to use cron for this, is you want the script run automatically. If so do you want it run at fixed rimes, e.g. once a day at 3am, or do you want it run when the machine boots,  or do you want it run every time a user logs in or something else?

Comment: I want this script to run automatically at boot.

Comment: How doesn't it "works"? What is expected, what is the outcome? You can set environment variables inside the crontab, see `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: You need to revise based on comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just copied essential environment variables to autorun script. Looks like hack but works.

Upd. I need to autorun script at boot as root. I works fine if started manually from regular user with sudo. But it doesn't work if started by cron (@reboot statement). To find out what's different I created small script that dumps to file output of these commands: id, env, iwconfig. Ran it 2 times: sudo from user and scheduled by cron. And from these logs found out that cron starts script with truncated environment, PATH looks short, it can't even find iwconfig. To fix the problem I copied with text editor 2 environment variables (PATH and SHELL) to original script. Script now looks the same, just with 2 additional strings on top:

export PATH=full_path_from_env

export SHELL=/bin/bash

and works fine.

Comment: What are the "essential" variables? How did you copy them? What did the script look like after you copied them? Please [edit] and give more details so the next person with the same problem can reproduce what you did.